# How to fit xticks with the plotted time series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several plots of data against time as follow:

[image]

For instance this time serie start the 2003.01 and finish the 2007.01. I don' tknow why matplotlib decided to put the xticks at some random location that are not really convenient to read a time serie. I wish to have a xtick at the beginning of the time serie and then another xtick at the beginning of each years.

I cannot use the ´xlim´ trick because I have around 1000 different plots.

Here is the code that I am currently using

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

def to_inch(cm):
    return cm/2.54 

rc('figure', **{
   "facecolor": "white",
   "figsize": (to_inch(11.7), to_inch(8.27),)
})

rc('text', usetex=False)
font = {
    'family': 'serif', 
    'serif': ['Computer Modern'],
    'size': 8
}
rc('font', **font)

labelsize = 6
linewidth = 0.5
axes = {
    'labelsize': labelsize,
    "edgecolor": '#cbcbcb', 
    "linewidth": linewidth,
    "facecolor": "white"
}
rc("grid", **{"linewidth": linewidth}) 
rc('axes', **axes)

rc('legend', **{'fontsize': 5})

rc('xtick', **{"labelsize": labelsize})
rc('ytick', **{"labelsize": labelsize})

nc = Dataset("o_gg.nc", 'r+')
#Get time
time = num2date(nc.variables['time'[:],getattr(nc.variables['time'],'units'))
time_ctr_ch = np.array([ xx-dt.timedelta(hours=12,minutes=15) for xx in time])
ctr_chtessel_soil = nc.variables['SoilMoist'][:,:,0,0]
plt.plot(time_ctr_ch, ctr_chtessel_soil, c='lightsteelblue', linewidth=0.5
```

Comment: If you don't share any code, one cannot help here.

Comment: Ok I will re-edit my question!

Comment: Just set the `xlim` to the min and max of your `x` values, you don't need to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) formatters and locators.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

y = np.random.rand(72)
x = pd.date_range('2011-03-01', periods= 72, freq= 'd')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work for what you are asking. Change to Years in a way that suits your code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
y = np.random.rand(72)
x = pd.date_range('2011-03-01', periods= 72, freq= 'd')


def get_strings(x):
    lst_strngs = []
    lst_strngs.append(str(x[0].date()))
    for i in range(1,72):
        if x[i].day==1:
            lst_strngs.append(str(x[i].date()))
        else:
            lst_strngs.append("")
    return lst_strngs
ax= plt.subplot()
plt.plot(x,y)

_=plt.xticks(x,get_strings(x))
```

That would give : [image]

Comment: Matplotlib provides [fomatters and locators](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) for such tasks.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest